# For loop and sequence function to create list of lists of dates is returning a shorter list than expected

Tags: r

I am using a for loop to create a list of list of dates with the date sequence from open date to closed date. My problem is that the list of list contains 41 items and not the 63 items that I need. The logic seems to be partly correct but the output is incomplete.

I am attempting to create a line graph in R that shows how many information security incidents are open at a point in time.

I read the csv with the data. Create three vectors from columns: date incident was opened, date incident was closed (if incident has not been closed I replace the NA with todays date), and incident number. I use lubridate to format the two date vectors as dates.

I create data frame with these three vectors and take the number of rows as a variable n (in this case its 63). I create an empty list and then run a for loop creating a list of lists, each item in the list is the sequence of dates from the open date to the closed date.

My problem is that the list of list contains 41 items and not the 63 items that I need.

```
library(lubridate)
```

## Read incident registry data

```
incidents.data <- read.csv("incidents2019.csv")

#Create vector for columns that with data of incident open date, incident closed dates and incident number
incident.open <- dmy(incidents.data$Date.Reported.to.InfoSecGov..Day.B.)
incident.closed <- mdy(incidents.data$Closing.Date..Day.I.)
incident.number <- incidents.data$Incident.Num
```

## No NA, replaced, in process closing dates with date of today.

```
incident.closed.full <- incident.closed %>% replace_na(as.Date        ("2019/6/12"))
```

## Create Data set with dates

```
data <- data.frame(incident.number, incident.open, incident.closed.full)

n <- nrow(data)
mylist <- list()

for(i in 1:n){
  mylist[[i]] <- seq(as.Date(data$incident.open[i]), as.Date     (data$incident.closed.full[i]), "days")
}

d <- do.call("c", mylist)

df <- data.frame(table(d))
```

## Plot data

```
plot(df$d, df$Freq, main = "Information Security Incidents In Process",     xlab="Date", ylab="# of InfoSec Incidents in Process")
lines(df$Freq)
```

I receive this error message:

> Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument

Comment: ```for(i in 1:n){
  mylist[[i]] <- seq(as.Date(data$incident.open[i]), as.Date     (data$incident.closed.full[i]), "days")
}```
is not working for me. Are you sure `seq()` is to be used this way? A source would be helpful

Comment: Please include `dput` or a sample near your actual. See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1422451). Much of this can be streamlined without the need of first `data.frame` call, *mylist*, `for` loop, or `do.call`. I see all processing with original data frame: *incidents.data*.